# Unable to get Weierstrass p symbol in latex

Tags: symbols, amsmath, amssymb

I am trying to write the symbol `$\wp$` in springer template, but I am getting output 'wp' instead of the symbol (`amssymb` and `amsmath` are also installed). Can anyone please help! 
https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18782940/data/Download+the+journal+article+template+package 
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{springer trial}
\author{ }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The symbol $\wp$ is not there.
\end{document}
```

In logs and output files, I am getting

```
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.(breakurl) \burl will be just a synonym of \url. on input line 48.
```

But I don't think the output error has anything to do with the symbol. It's there even after I remove the symbol code.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Were there any errors or warnings about this in your log file?  If so, please add that information to your question.  (A small compilable example demonstrating the problem would also be appreciated.)

Comment: I can replicate the OP's issue with the following test document: `\documentclass{sn-jnl} \begin{document} $\wp$ \end{document}`.

Comment: `sn-jnl ` loads the 'program` package causing the problem

Comment: With the documentclass as given by @Mico, I am getting this output: "Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.(breakurl) \burl will be just a synonym of \url. on input line 48."

Comment: @SimonDispa You are right! On commenting it in file sn-jnl.cls, the symbol appears. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some (unknown) reasons, the package loads the `program` package, that offers almost nothing useful, in my opinion.

This package does

```
%% require the {...} for \wp and \WP
\let\oldwp=\wp % save old \wp (curly p character)
%\def\wp#{\@wp}
%\def\@wp#1{\mbox{\normalshape wp}(#1)}
%\def\WP#{\@WP}
%\def\@WP#1{\mbox{\normalshape WP}(#1)}
%% Don't require {...}, ie use normal parentheses where required:
\def\wp{\mbox{\normalshape wp}}
\def\WP{\mbox{\normalshape WP}}
```

What such a (disputable as regards to code) redefinition of `\wp` is useful for, I don't know.

Anyway, you can use `\oldwp` instead.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{springer trial}
\author{ }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The symbol $\oldwp$ is not there.
\end{document}
```

[image]